# Argument type 'UITextField' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, if-statement

I'm currently watching a YouTube video, learning about user signup for an app I'm working on. I'm trying to make two text fields where you type in the password, to match. Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Registrer ny bruker")

    // Validate required fields are not empty
    if (firstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
        (lastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
        (emailAdressTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
        (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)!
    {
        // Display alert message and return
        return
    }

    // Validate password
    if ((passwordTextField.text?.elementsEqual(repeatPasswordTextField!))! != true) {
        return
    }        
}
```

On the "validate password" I get:

> Argument type 'UITextField' does not conform to expected type
>   'Sequence'

I'm new at this, I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: You can use `UIKeyInput` property `hasText` to check if your `UITextField` is empty `if !firstNameTextField.hasText {` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow. The issue you are having is because you are trying to see if a string contains a UITextField.

We could make this more elegant:

```
@IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Registrer ny bruker")

    guard let firstName = firstNameTextField.text,
      let lastName = lastNameTextField.text,
      let email = emailAdressTextField.text,
      let password = passwordTextField.text,
      let repeatedPassword = repeatPasswordTextField.text else {
          // If any of the values above is empty, just return
          return
      }

    // We avoid force unwrapping with the guard above
    // so the values we test for here are not optional 
    if firstName.isEmpty ||
       lastName.isEmpty ||
       password.isEmpty ||
       repeatedPassword.isEmpty {
        // Display alert message and return
        return
    }

    // Validate password
    if password != repeatedPassword {
        return
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No need to safely unwrap text property its default value is an empty string and it will never return nil

Comment: I haven’t checked to be honest if that optional string comes as an empty string or a nil but I think we can both agree it is not a good practice to force unwrap an optional.